# Autoscroll a UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have implemented a UITableView, which shows up fine as a subview in my iPhoneApp. Now this is supposed to be something similar to a tele prompter, so I would like to autoscroll this thing up, till the last cell is there.

I was playing around with -scrollToRowVisible, but this did not seem to work. Can anyone give me a hint here or point me to some example?

Comment: Where is `scrollToRowVisible` defined anyway? I don't see it anywhere in the iPhone SDK??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about [`scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW7)?

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks a lot... it worked like a charme! I definately need to lear to read more before I ask ;-)